# Can't Read Excel from sharepoint document library directly

Tags: c#, excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I have a document library on sharepoint 2010 which has multiple excels uploaded in it. Now I want to read these excels and convert it to datatable or XML.

I have already tried following approaches:

1. Copy the excel to local folder and use oledb query to read the data: Due to user's limited privileges this solution didn't work
2. Using Interop: It needs Excel installation on server so this solution also didn't work.
3. Using Excel services: Some of my files have macro and data validations and we don't have permission to change server settings. So this solution didn't work.
4. Using third party tool: Our client don't want to use any third party tools.

Comment: What was the problem with point 1) accessing data from list or 2) saving excel file or 3) fetching data from excel file.

Comment: Due to the limited permission we are not able to save the excel file on server.

Comment: Can you paste your code, how you are saving excel file on server.

Comment: Actually, we are currently in development phase and we are  developing the application on our local environment, the functionality to copy the file and read it from there is just working fine in dev. But our client doesn't want that we copy the excel in their environment.

Comment: Try using OpenXML to read from the spreadsheet. This doesn't require any Office installations or special permissions in the server.

Comment: Thanks Prashant, Can I use a simple select query like oledb in OpenXML?